# Cakephp 3.6.14: Controller get post request, reopen view and copy form elements

Tags: php, post, cakephp, request, cakephp-3.x

I want when the user submits the form then the contents of this form will be saved in the database but then it will redirect to the same form with the fields same as the previous one so the user can edit some of them and save it again. How I can achieve that?

**CODE**

**add.ctp:**

```
<div class="roles form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
<?= $this->Form->create($role) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Role') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('name');
        echo $this->Form->control('description');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

**RolesController.php (add function)**

```
public function add()
{
    $role = $this->Roles->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $role = $this->Roles->patchEntity($role, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Roles->save($role)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The role has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The role could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('role'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For staying on the same page / form just remove the `return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index'])` - but I don't think that's what you really want. The user would be dead ended on the "add" page - just adding more entities...

Check out the [CakePHP Controller tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/articles-controller.html) - it shows how to create the `edit` method and template. After doing so you have to change the redirect to something like `return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit', $role->get('name')])` (assuming that the `name` property is appropriate for identifying role entities).